# How to write a general function callback test class?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates

I have several classes which each store and call a callback function.  The callback functions' signatures have different parameter and return types, but all of them take just one parameter.

To verify that these classes call their callbacks when they should, I'm trying to write a general test class which (1) provides a callback function which takes one parameter, (2) lets the user query whether that function has been called, and (3) lets the user examine the parameter which was passed to that function.  So far, I have something like this:

```
template<class ReturnType, class ParameterType> class Callable
{
    public:
        Callable() : m_called(false), m_param() {}
        ReturnType operator()(ParameterType param)
        {
            m_called = true;
            m_param = param;
            return Returntype();
        }
        bool Called() { return m_called; }
        ParameterType Param() { return m_param; }

    private:
        bool m_called;
        ParameterType m_param;
};
```

Here's a class which might be tested using class Callable:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class ToBeTested
{
    ToBeTested(boost::function<bool (int)> callback) : m_callback(callback) {};
    boost::function<bool (int)> m_callback;

    //  (methods which should cause the callback to be called here)
};
```

Here's some test code:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

int main(int, char**)
{
    Callable<bool, int> callable;
    ToBeTested tbt(boost::bind(&Callable<bool, int>::operator());

    //  (tell tbt it should call its callback here)

    if (callable.Called()
    {
        if (EXPECTED_VALUE == callable.Param();
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This gives me (1) and (2), but there's a problem with (3) when the callback takes its parameter by reference: Callable::m_param is a reference type and therefore can't be default initialised.  I could fix that by making Callable::operator() take its parameter by reference, like this:

```
    ReturnType operator()(ParameterType & param)
```

...but then I can't use class Callable when the callback function takes its parameter by value.

Is there a way to make my test class work regardless of whether the callback function takes its parameter by reference, or do I need to write two nearly-identical test classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, where references are actually stored as pointers:

```
template<typename T>
struct ref_to_ptr
{
    typedef T type;

    static T wrap(T x) { return x; }
    static T unwrap(T x) { return x; }
};

template<typename T>
struct ref_to_ptr<T&>
{
    typedef T* type;

    static T* wrap(T& x) { return &x; }
    static T& unwrap(T* x) { return *x; }
};

template<class ReturnType, class ParameterType> class Callable
{
    public:
        Callable() : m_called(false), m_param() {}
        ReturnType operator()(ParameterType param)
        {
            m_called = true;
            m_param = ref_to_ptr<ParameterType>::wrap(param);
            return Returntype();
        }
        bool Called() { return m_called; }
        ParameterType Param() { return ref_to_ptr<ParameterType>::unwrap(m_param); }

    private:
        bool m_called;
        typename ref_to_ptr<ParameterType>::type m_param;
};
```

Comment: Thanks - my coworkers and I just learned something that we didn't know templates could do.  :-)